# Gráfico do ggplot com vãos sem que existam NA's

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico de linhas que compare o PIB nominal com o PIB real. Estou usando os dados do IBGE com o pacote `sidrar`, além do pacote `tidyverse` e o `janitor` para manipular os dados, além do `deflateBR` para conseguir os valores reais do PIB com preços de 2015:

```
pib <- get_sidra(api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/all/c11255/90687,90691,90696,90707/d/v585%200") %>% 
    clean_names() %>% 
    select(trimestre_codigo, valor, setores_e_subsetores)  %>% 
    filter(trimestre_codigo >= '2015 Q1') %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = setores_e_subsetores, values_from=valor) %>% 
    mutate(presidente = case_when(trimestre_codigo < '2016 Q1' ~ "Dilma",
                               trimestre_codigo >= '2016 Q1' & trimestre_codigo < '2019 Q1' ~ "Temer",
                               trimestre_codigo >= '2019 Q1' ~ 'Bolsonaro',
  ))

pib$trimestre_codigo <- as.yearqtr(pib$trimestre_codigo,format='%Y%q')

pibreal <- deflate(pib[,5], nominal_dates = as.Date(pib$trimestre), real_date = '01-2015', index = 'ipca')
pib<- cbind(pib,pibreal)

nomes <- c('trimestre', "agropecuaria", "industria", "servicos", "pib","presidente", "pib_real_2015")
colnames(pib.corrente) <- nomes
```

Com esses dados consigo fazer um gráfico simples comparando o PIB nominal e o real como esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código usado foi:

```
ggplot(pib.corrente) +
  geom_line(aes(x = trimestre, y = pib, size = 1, color = 'black') +
  geom_line(aes(x = trimestre, y = pib_real_2015, color = , size = 1, color = '#69b3a2') +
  labs(x = "Trimestre", y = "R$ (Milhões)", caption = 'Fonte: Elaboração própria com dados do IBGE',
       title = 'PIB Nominal X PIB real de 2015') +
  theme_light()
ggsave("pib nominal e real.png")
```

A questão é que queria destacar o período de cada governo e para isso adicionei a opção `color = presidente` dentro de cada `aes()`, ficando assim:

```
ggplot(pib.corrente) +
  geom_line(aes(x = trimestre, y = pib, color = as.factor(presidente)), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = trimestre, y = pib_real_2015, color = 
                  as.factor(presidente)), size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Trimestre", y = "R$ (Milhões)", caption = 'Fonte: Elaboração própria com dados do IBGE',
       title = 'PIB Nominal X PIB real de 2015') +
  theme_light()
```

O problema é que sai do seguinte modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei trocar o `geom_line()` por `geom_path()` e também tentei colocar a opção `color =` fora do `aes()`: `geom_line(aes(x = trimestre, y = pib), size = 1, color = as.factor(presidente))` sem sucesso.

O que posso fazer para que as linhas do último gráfico fiquem contínuas?

Comment: Cara, eu acho que isso ocorre porque um gráfico em linha é basicamente união entre pontos. Quando tu separaste as cores, pontos ficaram separados... Tenta fazer um overlap (alguns pontos comuns nas fronteiras entre as cores) em vez de separar por anos. Mas, isso é um chute - eu não conheço R nem ggplot2...

Comment: Parece que é exatamente próximo às mudanças de presidente. A coluna presidente no seu dataframe esstá toda preenchida? Veja se nestes períodos, a coluna presidente tem NA. Teste fazendo drop de NA. Se estiver usando `dplyr` seria algo como `%>% filter(!is.na(presidente))`

Comment: eu tinha conferido isso antes de postar aqui e estava tudo completo, sem NA's. Desculpe, esqueci de citar

Answer (score 4):

Vou usar um exemplo genérico para facilitar a reprodução por outros usuários:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dados <- data.frame(
  ano = 2001:2012,
  irrelevante = 5:16,
  nivel_a = Nile[1:12],
  qualquer = letters[2:13],
  nivel_b = Nile[1:12] + 1:12*100,
  grupo = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4))
```

Como apontado nos comentários, linhas são criadas ligando os pontos dos dados. Ao quebrar em grupos de cor está definindo 3 linhas distintas, sem conexão entre elas:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = ano, color = grupo)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = nivel_a)) + geom_point(aes(y = nivel_a))  +
  geom_line(aes(y = nivel_b)) + geom_point(aes(y = nivel_b))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode usar `geom_segment` ao invés de `geom_line`, atribuindo a cor de cada segmento pelo grupo (presidentes, no seu caso). Para isso, precisa gerar um novo *data.frame* com a informação das coordenadas de início e fim de cada segmento.

```
dados.s <- dados %>%
  mutate(across(c("ano", starts_with("nivel")), ~lead(.x), .names = '{col}.f')) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))

ggplot(dados.s, aes(ano, xend = ano.f, color = grupo)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = nivel_a, yend = nivel_a.f)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = nivel_b, yend = nivel_b.f))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Testei aqui e ao delcarar "dados.s" troquei o ".x" por ".trimestre" porém retorna erro (object not found) ) e quando uso apenas "trimestre" o mapa sai esquisito. não tem que fazer algo a mais para definir ".trimestre"?

Comment: notei que declarando só trimestre, sem o ponto, funciona o código mostrando quando termina cada período, mas mesmo assim o gráfico sai com linhas verticais para cada período. creio que o problema então esteja em usar as.yearqtr(), seria bom usar como "as date"?

Comment: Desculpe, mal hábito de escrever código compacto. O `.x` não é a coluna *x*, mas o equivalente a `function(x)`; está indicando para aplicar `lead` a cada uma das colunas especificadas (no meu exemplo, da *x* até a *y2*). No seu caso: `mutate(across(c("trimestre", starts_with("pib")), ~lead(.x), .names = '{col}.f'))`. Vou editar a resposta para não ficar ambíguo.

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de não ser isto o pedido na pergunta, com os presidentes a definirem as cores não há cores diferentes para os dois PIB's e creio que é melhor deixar as cores das linhas para os PIB's e ter os presidentes assinalados em cores de fundo do gráfico.

### Dados

Primeiro carregar os pacotes que vão ser utilizados e baixar os dados.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(janitor)
  library(zoo)
  library(sidrar)
  library(deflateBR)
  library(viridis)
})

pib <- get_sidra(api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/all/c11255/90687,90691,90696,90707/d/v585%200") %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  select(trimestre_codigo, valor, setores_e_subsetores)  %>% 
  filter(trimestre_codigo >= '2015 Q1') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = setores_e_subsetores, values_from = valor) %>% 
  mutate(presidente = case_when(
    trimestre_codigo < '2016 Q1' ~ "Dilma",
    trimestre_codigo >= '2016 Q1' & trimestre_codigo < '2019 Q1' ~ "Temer",
    trimestre_codigo >= '2019 Q1' ~ 'Bolsonaro',
  ))

pib$trimestre_codigo <- as.yearqtr(pib$trimestre_codigo, format = '%Y%q')

pibreal <- deflate(
  nominal_values = pib[, 5], 
  nominal_dates = as.Date(pib$trimestre_codigo), 
  real_date = '01-2015', 
  index = 'ipca'
)
pib.corrente <- cbind(pib, pibreal)

nomes <- c('trimestre', "agropecuaria", "industria", "servicos", "pib", "presidente", "pib_real_2015")
colnames(pib.corrente) <- nomes
```

---

### Tabelas

O gráfico é baseado em duas tabelas, uma tabela para as linhas dos PIB's e outra para as áreas dos presidentes.

```
pib.plot <- pib.corrente %>%
  select(-(2:4)) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with('pib'),
    names_to = 'pib',
    values_to = 'R$'
  ) %>%
  mutate(pib = if_else(pib == 'pib', 'PIB Nominal', 'PIB Real de 2015'))

pib.rect <- pib.corrente %>%
  select(-(2:4)) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('pib'), names_to = 'pib') %>% 
  group_by(presidente, pib) %>%
  summarise(xstart = first(trimestre), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(xstart) %>%
  group_by(pib) %>%
  mutate(xend = lead(xstart, default = as.yearqtr(Sys.Date()))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(presidente = factor(presidente, levels = c('Dilma', 'Temer', 'Bolsonaro'))) %>%
  select(-pib)
```

---

### Gráfico

Finalmente o gráfico.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    data = pib.rect,
    mapping = aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = presidente),
    alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(
    data = pib.plot,
    mapping = aes(trimestre, `R$`, color = pib),
    size = 1.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`PIB Nominal` = 'black', `PIB Real de 2015` = '#69b3a2')) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "H") +
  labs(
    x = "Trimestre", 
    y = "R$ (Milhões)", 
    caption = 'Fonte: Elaboração própria com dados do IBGE',
    title = 'PIB Nominal X PIB Real de 2015') +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(title = "PIB"),
    fill = guide_legend(title = "Presidente")) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>